# Recent update blew out audio

Tags: sound, updates

I have a Dell XPS 13 (2015) with the recent BIOS update installed before installing Ubuntu. Before the recent upgrades below, my audio was working fine. After rebooting, the update destroyed the audio capability on my laptop and as a result I have no output of sound. I have checked all sound channels to see if they were muted (they're not) and I have cold-rebooted twice but to no avail. I checked the update log and here's the output:

```
    Start-Date: 2015-09-05  10:47:03
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.94'
Upgrade: libvdpau1:amd64 (0.9-1, 0.9-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2015-09-05  10:47:04

Start-Date: 2015-09-06  17:07:03
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.100'
Install: libbonobo2-common:amd64 (2.32.1-3, automatic), libidl0:amd64 (0.8.14-1, automatic), libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (2.24.5-0ubuntu4, automatic), python-vte:amd64 (0.28.2-5ubuntu1, automatic), libkeybinder0:amd64 (0.3.0-3build1, automatic), libglade2-0:amd64 (2.6.4-2, automatic), python-pyorbit:amd64 (2.24.0-7ubuntu1, automatic), libgnome2-common:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1, automatic), python-keybinder:amd64 (0.3.0-3build1, automatic), python-gnome2:amd64 (2.28.1+dfsg-1.1, automatic), libgnomeui-common:amd64 (2.24.5-3, automatic), libgnomecanvas2-0:amd64 (2.30.3-2, automatic), libbonoboui2-common:amd64 (2.24.5-0ubuntu4, automatic), terminator:amd64 (0.97-4), libbonobo2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-3, automatic), python-gconf:amd64 (2.28.1+dfsg-1.1, automatic), libgnome2-0:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1, automatic), libgnomecanvas2-common:amd64 (2.30.3-2, automatic), libgnomeui-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3, automatic), libgnome2-bin:amd64 (2.32.1-4ubuntu1, automatic), liborbit-2-0:amd64 (2.14.19-0.3, automatic), liborbit2:amd64 (2.14.19-0.3, automatic)`
End-Date: 2015-09-06  17:07:11
```

I don't know which packages broke my audio, and because there's no rollback feature on Ubuntu I can't restore my system to a previous date. As a result, I need to know which packages to uninstall so as to install an earlier update of the menacing package.

I can still watch videos, whether flash-based or not; but there's just no audio whatsoever. It's not limited to a browser, it's affected the entire system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not because of an update. It is a known bug with the I2S Audio Interface.

Simply do two cold reboots (fully shut down your computer twice). This will fix the audio issue.

*Note : If you are using dual boot setup, you will need two cold reboots **everytime** you switch from one OS to another (Windows to Ubuntu, Ubuntu to Windows...)*

Refer to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1413446) for more information.